# How to grep full words between spaces

Tags: bash, grep

For example, I have a string like this: `1341 5415 fdad`.

Command `grep -E "(^|\s)[1-9]{1,5}($|\s)" -o` will give only `1341`, but I want to get `1341` and `5415`.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The actual match you get is `1341␣`, with the trailing space. And grep doesn't look for overlapping matches, so when that space is taken by the first match, the pattern doesn't match again on the rest of the line. But if the input was `123 456 789`, the two strings `123␣` and `␣789` would be matched.

It's probably easier to use `grep -w`:

> `-w`, `--word-regexp`
> Select  only  those  lines  containing  matches that form whole words.  The test is that the matching substring must either be at the beginning of the line, or preceded by a non-word
> constituent character.

```
$ echo '1341 5415 fdad' |  grep -wE "[1-9]{1,5}" -o
1341
5415
```

Alternatively, you could double all spaces before the grep:

```
$ echo '1341 5415 fdad' | sed -e 's/ /  /g' | grep -E "(^|\s)[1-9]{1,5}($|\s)" -o
1341 
 5415
```

(or with `sed -e 's/\s/  /g'` if that works in your sed.)

There's a trailing space in `1341` line, and a leading one in the `5415`, those are part of the matches.

Comment: Very clever. Now we will never know whether I would have discovered on my own...

Comment: But now for input "1341+1234" I will get 1341 and 1234 instead of empty output

Comment: @ВиталийЕгоров, if separators other than space were part of your issue, you could have said so in the question...

Comment: @ilkkachu, thank you very much, you've helped me a lot

Answer (score 6):

```
echo '1341 5415 fdad' | grep -E -o '\b[1-9]{1,5}\b'
```

Output:

```
1341
5415
```

> `-E`: Interpret PATTERNS as extended regular expression

> `-o`: Print only the matched (non-empty) parts of a matching line, with each such part on a separate output line.

> `\b`: [zero-width word boundary](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6664167/3776858)

Answer (score 3):

One method is to change all spaces to a newline, then use `grep -x` to select lines that exactly match your expression:

```
$ echo '1341 5415 fdad' | tr -s '[:space:]' '[\n*]' | grep -xE -e '[1-9]{1,5}'
1341
5415
```

Comment: should work with just `tr -s '[:space:]' '\n'` since `tr` is supposed to extend the second list of characters by repeating the last one as necessary to match the length of the first